# Manag [managment]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Given the 33 questions currently tagged [managment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managment), and the *zero* questions tagged [management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management), it appears to be an attempt to work around a blacklisted tag. Most of its uses are of the "C&P title or summary blindly into tag field" variety.

Anything I should be aware of before it is righteously cleansed in purging fire?

Comment: Just go ahead. Though try to do better edits than simply robo-removing the mispelled bad tag.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Of course. There will probably be a few flaggings as well.

Comment: @CarrieKendall: That was the joke.

Comment: I was just passing by, apologies for being the destroyer of puns :)

Comment: Looks like someone has cleared this tag, there are no questions coming up for it.

Comment: @KevinBrown: I guess that's what happens when you lose Internet for a while.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just go ahead and remove the tag. "Management" questions seem to fall under these categories:

- Actually referring to [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management), those questions need to be re-tagged. Although [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) is a rather fishy tag too, it has a very broad meaning.
- Managing "something": licenses, installations etc. In that case the tag should just be removed as it is just a nonsense tag that doesn't make the question easier to find.
- Less likely: management as in being a boss, or alternatively project management. Should you find any such question, it is off-topic for this site and needs to get flagged/closed.